# AngularJs scope.apply seems to break autcomplete jquery ui

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, autocomplete, angularjs-directive

I have some trouble trying to implement an autocomplete field into a directive using Jquery-UI.

Let me explain.
Here is my html element :

```
<div class="form-group" >
  <input type="text" placeholder="Find a category" data-category-autocomplete data-append-to=".autocomplete-container" data-ng-model="categories" class="form-control login-field" name="category_find"></input>
  <div class="autocomplete-container"></div>
</div>
```

Now, here is the angular js directive :

```
app.directive('categoryAutocomplete', function(HomeService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                elem.autocomplete({
                    source: function(request, response) {
                        HomeService.search_category(this.term).then(function(success) {
                            response(success);
                        }, function(error) {
                            response("");
                        });

                    }, select: function(event, ui) {
                         scope.choose_category(ui.item.id, ui.item.label, true);
                         scope.$apply();
                    }
                    , appendTo : attrs.appendTo
                }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                    item.label = item.title;
                    item.id = item.id_category;
                    var categoryLine = $("<a>").html(item.title);

                    return $('<li>').append($("<a>").append(categoryLine).html()).appendTo(ul);
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

And finally, the choose category function :

```
$scope.choose_category = function(id_category, label) {
    $scope.category = label;
    $scope.id_category = id_category;
};
```

So, it is working well at the first use. Let me explain every steps :

1. Typing some caracters with results into my field
2. Select one result
3. My selection is ok, and the autocomplete field is reseting
   This works well
4. Now I want to make another search, so I type someting new
5. The results shows up, but i can't click on it anymore, it is like I wan't go into "select" of my autocomplete directive, but the "source" works well

As you can see, it is like i can select only one time my autocomplete result, but the scope.apply(); seems to "break" the selection possibility on a second search.

Does anyone see my problem?

Thanks for any help you can provide !

Comment: can't append an `<a>` to another `<a>` , that's invalid html. Create a demo that replicates your problem

Comment: @Mayous does it give any error in console?

Comment: before applying a scope you should always check phase. the statement should be if(!scope.$$phase) scope.$apply()

Comment: Hi all and thanks for your help.
I followed @charlietfl advise and create a sample on jsfiddle, and the code is working well. To make my post more relevant, I removed some other unusefull code, but I think some of this code is the problem now. I'll be back with more information about the peace of code which make my autcomplete field stop working !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I resolved my Problem.
Here is what was going wrong.

My autocomplete field is hidden into a custom select list.

I also created a custom directive which close my custom select when you click outside of it, here it is :

```
app.directive('clickAnywhereButHere', function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
          elem.bind('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
          });
          $document.bind('click', function() {
            // magic here.
            scope.$apply(attr.clickAnywhereButHere);
          })
        }
      };
});
```

The problem is : e.stopPropagation(); It works well for the first time i click to choose a result, but the second time, my event is stopped, so it won't continue working.

I moved the call of the clickAnywhereButHere() call, and now it works well.

To undertsand it in a better way, here is a sample of code working :
http://jsfiddle.net/acha1cL1/1/
Here is a sample of code broken I was using (see the difference on the html code)  : http://jsfiddle.net/2yL62fyq/2/

Thanks again for you help !